# Correctness of Using the First Sentence

Tags: present-perfect

I would like to know which of the following sentences is more correct and should I write an auxiliary verb twice like in the first one (for instance: I was reading book and having coffee or I was reading book and was having coffee).

```
Someone has fallen off the ladder and has hurt the leg.
Someone has fallen off the ladder and hurt the leg.
```

Comment: It's better to use *a leg* or *their leg* instead of *the leg*, but otherwise both forms are fine.

Comment: I think it's called a [conjunction reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51930/i-verb-and-am-rest-of-sentence/51955#51955)

Comment: @Lawrence that seems like an answer - do you want to write it in the answer box?

Comment: @Lawrence, so as far as I understand I can write `has fallen off and has broken ` and `has fallen off and broken` like in the case `I was reading book and was having coffee` and `I was reading book and  having coffee` with no difference in meaning and both of them are grammatically correct? Sorry if something is wrong I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Although we commonly speak of *hurting his/her/their leg* when we have two such limbs, you can also write *hurt a leg* (the implication being that it belongs to the person who fell rather than someone under the ladder).

Comment: *@bdsl* *Done*.

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov Yes, both are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a preliminary remark: using the definite article with *leg* indicates that the context specifies which leg is meant. For example, there might be a leg of ham near the ladder, and the consequences of the fall rendered it inedible. However, *hurt* is a somewhat cryptic way of describing such damage. If *leg* referred to one of the limbs of the climber, consider using a different determiner instead, for example, *a* leg or *their* leg.

Let's pick one of these and continue:

- Someone has fallen off the ladder and (has) hurt their leg.

We can split this into the following sentences:

1. Someone has fallen off the ladder.
2. Someone has hurt their leg.
3. Someone hurt their leg.

Note that because *hurt* is used for both perfect and simple past, both #2 and #3 are grammatically correct.

Let's see what happens when we replace *hurt* with a word that has a different past and perfect form, such as *take* (take - took - has taken). To avoid unnecessary unpleasant imagery, we'll go back to the *ham* leg for this, though I'd admit that the scenario becomes rather contrived.

4. Someone has fallen off the ladder and took the leg.

This parses as:

5. someone has fallen off the ladder, and
6. the same person took the leg.

The two parts are only loosely connected.

If we use *has taken*, we can produce the following sentences:

7. Someone has fallen off the ladder and taken the leg.
8. Someone has fallen off the ladder and has taken the leg.

These are similar in structure to your original sentences. #7 is an [elided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) version of #8 in the sense that a word has been removed from #8, but the sentence is still considered to be well-formed, with the same meaning.

The closest type of ellipsis for this form that I found is called [gapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapping). The term comes from the (single) gap produced when words in the full sentence are removed:

> In linguistics, gapping is a type of ellipsis that occurs in the non-initial conjuncts of coordinate structures.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) Gapping usually elides minimally a finite verb and further any non-finite verbs that are present. This material is "gapped" from the non-initial conjuncts of a coordinate structure.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapping)

In this case, *has* isn't used as a verb, as it would be in a sentence like "He has a meat pie". nevertheless, I think it still counts as ellipsis in the widest sense:

> In linguistics, ellipsis (from the Greek: ἔλλειψις, élleipsis, "omission") or elliptical construction refers to the omission from a clause of one or more words that are nevertheless understood in the context of the remaining elements.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))

Linguists can continue the analysis into [coordinate structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_(linguistics)) etc, but the above is probably sufficient to answer your question about the auxiliary verb *has*: yes, both are fine, albeit with the caveat about "the".

Comment: Awesome. Great explanation. And I'm sorry about the delay in response to your answer.

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov No problem. Thanks for coming back, and glad the answer helped! :)

Comment: hope so) I  admire  the English languge. How powerful and colorful it is!!!